# Regex: Match alphanumeric and spaces with exception of leading spaces

Tags: regex, bash, text

My goal is to capture alphanumeric characters and all spaces (minus the leading space).
The issue I am having is not being able to capture spaces that follow non-alphanumeric characters (symbols).
I am willing to use look-arounds if necessary, but have yet to solve this even when doing so.

Here is what I have accomplished, as described above:

---

**Text:** `` # one 123: two `three` four (five) six ``

**Desired result:** `one 123 two three four five six`

---

***Regex attempts:**

with look-around:

`(?! )[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?<! )`

result:
`one 123twothreefourfivesix`

without look around:

`[A-Za-z0-9]+(?: +[A-Za-z0-9]+)*`

result: `one 123twothreefourfive`

Comment: Why is this tagged C *and* bash? And what regular expression library are you using?

Comment: And what part of that string do you want to match? "abc 123"?

Comment: can you please post some example and what will be expected output

Comment: I've fixed tags, clarified example, and provided results of my examples

Comment: @Shawn for now, I believe it is the POSIX regexp library (using it in a grep command)... I am open to using a javascript variant, though....
I have updated my question with desired result and clarified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^[^a-z0-9]+|[^a-z0-9 ]+|\s{2,}|[^a-z0-9]+$
```

- `^[^a-z0-9]+` - Matches anything else than alphanumeric at start of string
- `[^a-z0-9 ]+` - Matches anything else than alphanumeric and space
- `\s{2,}` - Matches two or more consecutive space characters
- `[^a-z0-9 ]+$` - Matches anything else than alphanumeric at end of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Zt1sKW/3/)